# Finding tuple in the list of tuples (sorting by multiple keys)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find tuple in the list of tuple, but not getting how to do that

I have the following `list (id, price, count)`

```
[('1', 3.0, 6), ('2', 2.0, 2), ('3', 2.0, 5), ('4', 4.0, 2), ('5', 2.0, 5), ('
6', 3.0, 6), ('7', 3.0, 5), ('8', 2.0, 5), ('9', 3.0, 5), ('10', 3.0, 5)]
```

condition for finding tuple is:

1. tuple should have minimum `price`.
2. tuple should have maximum count `value`.
3. priority of first condition is higher then second condition.

Please tell me how to achieve these conditions to find tuple in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build key for [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) from two elements of your list items: `(price, -count)` (*minus* count used to invert direction - bigger value will be first in result):

```
t = [('1', 3.0, 6), ('2', 2.0, 2), ('3', 2.0, 5), ('4', 4.0, 2), ('5', 2.0, 5),
     ('6', 3.0, 6), ('7', 3.0, 5), ('8', 2.0, 5), ('9', 3.0, 5), ('10', 3.0, 5)]

>>> sorted(t, key=lambda i: (i[1], -i[2]))
[('3', 2.0, 5), ('5', 2.0, 5), ('8', 2.0, 5), ('2', 2.0, 2), ('1', 3.0, 6),
 ('6', 3.0, 6), ('7', 3.0, 5), ('9', 3.0, 5), ('10', 3.0, 5), ('4', 4.0, 2)]
```

To find only one element you can use [min](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function with same tuple as key argument:

```
>>> min(t, key=lambda i: (i[1], -i[2]))
('3', 2.0, 5)
```

Comment: It sort tuples the way you want. Just pick up the first.

Comment: how did you make sure that i[1] will get priority over -i[2]?

Comment: When sorting with tuples as key, it always looks at the first element, and uses the second only if the first was equal. So that's automatic.

Comment: @subh.singh Do you care to sort all of the list or you want just the best tuple? In this case use Abhijit answer, which will take less time and less space to compute.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the [min](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)/[max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) builtin function to search your tile. Either of them would work, its only that you need to change the key function to use one over the other

For numerical values, negating a value changes its order

`a > b -> -a < -b`. Using this knowledge you can build a key as a tuple of two elements, the order depends on the order of priority. Based on whether you use max/min, you need to negate the appropriate variables,

```
>>> min(t, key = lambda e: (e[1], -e[2]))
('3', 2.0, 5)
>>> max(t, key = lambda e: (-e[1], e[2]))
('3', 2.0, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on multiple keys by the method mentioned in [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts).

```
x = [('1', 3.0, 6), ('2', 2.0, 2), ('3', 2.0, 5), ('4', 4.0, 2), ('5', 2.0, 5),
     ('6', 3.0, 6), ('7', 3.0, 5), ('8', 2.0, 5), ('9', 3.0, 5), ('10', 3.0, 5)]
```

Sort by second priority key `count` first:

```
x1 = sorted(x, key=lambda t: t[2], reverse=True)
```

Then sort the result by the first key 'price`:

```
x2 = sorted(x1, key=lambda t: t[1])
```

Now the optimal tuple is the first element of `x2`. Find all values matching the optimal value in x2:

```
optimal = (x2[0][1], x2[0][2])
[v for v in x2 if v[1]==optimal[0] and v[2]==optimal[1]]
# -> [('3', 2.0, 5), ('5', 2.0, 5), ('8', 2.0, 5)]
```

Comment: Why are you using `sorted` twice? Use it once to obtain `x1` and then call `x1.sort` to avoid yet an other copy of the list.

Comment: I prefer to treat the list in an immutable manner. Nothing wrong with using `sort` thought.