# sorting lists with multiple keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like the following:

```
[[2, 5, "bicycle"],
[1, 4, "table"],
[5, 2, "stew"],
[2, 2, "seesaw"],
...
]
```

How could I sort this list in the most readable way, if the main key would be the first element and the secondary key is the second element, in case there are multiple of the first element?

Comment: I would sort it using an inbuilt sorting method. Then go through and sort by secondary key if the key repeats more than once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding tuple in the list of tuples (sorting by multiple keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453264/finding-tuple-in-the-list-of-tuples-sorting-by-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with `key` parameter:

```
lst = [[2, 5, "bicycle"],
[1, 4, "table"],
[5, 2, "stew"],
[2, 2, "seesaw"]]

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])))
# [[1, 4, 'table'], [2, 2, 'seesaw'], [2, 5, 'bicycle'], [5, 2, 'stew']]
```

`(x[0], x[1])` part basically asks Python to sort by first element and then by second element in case first element is duplicate.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was a thing. It wasn't even in the manual entry that ForceBru so kindly sent me in his comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in allows you to specify custom keys. There is also a useful [how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) on multi-key sorts. Adapting your example to theirs

```
l = [[2, 5, "bicycle"],
[1, 4, "table"],
[5, 2, "stew"],
[2, 2, "seesaw"],
...
]

s = sorted(l, key=lambda o: o[1])     # sort on secondary key
sorted(s, key=lambda o: o[0])         # now sort on primary key
```

Answer (score 0):

The **sort()** method can be used. The basic syntax is:

```
list.sort(key=...)
```

Here, I have created a function and passed that function as the key in sort() method which returns 1st and 2nd element.

```
def get_key(item):
    return item[0], item[1]

mylist = [[2, 5, "bicycle"], [1, 4, "table"], [5, 2, "stew"], [2, 2, "seesaw"]]
mylist.sort(key=get_key)
print(mylist)
```